# NGINX redirect from language prefix to language domain

Tags: nginx

The web site currently has a language prefix paths, like www.example.com/de www.example.com/en
The idea is to remove all language prefixes and redirect user to the appropriate language domain.

For example, user opens a link to www.example.com/en/news and nginx redirect user to en.example.com/news

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

```
rewrite "^/([a-z]{2})(/.*)$" http://$1.example.com$2 permanent;
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/r/rewrite
- `man pcresyntax`